# unexpected minflt(minor page fault)

Tags: c++, linux

minor page fault means:need virtual memory map real memory, but I found my test code has some min page fault when access used memory .
my test code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint64_t len = 1024ll * 128; //128k
    uint32_t times = 1000000000;
    char *p = new char[len];
    for (uint32_t t = 0; t < times; ++t) {
      for (uint64_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
          *(p + i) = 100;
      }
    }
    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}
```

pidstat:

```
03:40:05 PM   UID       PID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ    RSS   %MEM  Command
03:40:06 PM     0     42379     34.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:07 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:08 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:09 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:10 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:11 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:12 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:13 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:14 PM     0     42379     34.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:15 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:16 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:17 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:18 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:19 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:20 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:21 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:22 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:23 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:24 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:25 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:26 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:27 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:28 PM     0     42379     34.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:29 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
03:40:30 PM     0     42379      0.00      0.00   12672   1196   0.00  main
```

minflt/s:34 = 34 * 4K = 136K

my array in test code = 128K

Why dost my test code product minflt when access used memory?

Comment: Why `*(p + i) = 128;` instead of `p[i] = 128;`? Also, `128` will likely overflow. `char` is usually 8 bits and signed which makes the greatest value it can hold 127.

Comment: I change my code. and ```g++ main.cc -o main -std=c++11 -O2```

Comment: Better, but prefer the C++ header `<cstdint>` over the C header `<stdint.h>` - and you don't need `<iostream>, `stdlib.h` or the non-C++-standard `unistd.h` for this program. Sidenote. Newer `g++` and `clang++` [optimizes the whole program away](https://godbolt.org/z/ao3o5337K).